# list index out of range - finding duplicate in sorted list

Tags: python

I'm brand new to Python, have only worked with PHP and front end language so Python syntax is confusing me.

As a simple task I want to check for duplicates in a sorted list and return true if one is found, without iterating through the remainder of the list.

Each time I try to do this, however, I'm receiving the

> IndexError: list index out of range

message.

The code:

```
    for n in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[n+1] < len(numbers):
            if numbers[n] == numbers[n+1]:
                return True
    return False
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've guessed the error means I'm trying to access an index that doesn't exist in the list, but I thought that `if numbers[n+1] <= len(numbers):` would mean I check every index other than the last (which would be out of range if I did).

EDIT: Although there are a number of ways to change the list and remove duplicates i.e. sets, I'm looking to learn the basic syntax and workings of Python at the moment, so working with the list itself is preferable.

Comment: But you *try to access that index*. You should probably meant to check `if n+1 < len(numbers)`

Comment: To your EDIT: See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need indices at all. Zip the list with its own tail, and look for duplicate tuples:

```
from itertools import slice
for x, y in zip(numbers, islice(numbers, 1, None)):
    if x == y:
        return True
return False
```

Using indices, it's simply

```
for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
    if numbers[i] == numbers[i+1]:
        return True
return False
```

You need to make sure `i` never gets set to the last index, so that `numbers[i+1]` can't try to access an element past the end of the array.

Comment: Keeping as a list was preferable for now, as I'm trying to work with the most basic of syntax before moving onto anything else.

If you don't mind me asking, what if the list wasn't sorted? How would I look for a duplicate? (Without sorting it first) - would I be looking at using nested if iterations?

Comment: If the elements are hashable (and `int`s are), you can add the elements to a set and check if the resulting set has the same size as the list (as several other answers demonstrate). Depending on how large you list is, it might still be more efficient to sort it than to deal with the overhead of a second data structure.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply convert to set and compare len

```
def check_no_duplicates(numbers):
    return len(numbers) == len(set(numbers))
```

will return `True` if there is no duplicate and `False` otherwise.

EDIT: This will work if your list consists of hashable objects, e.g. int. It will not work if elements of the list are unhashable e.g. lists. Assuming you have numbers in the list this not will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list first and then check if any duplicate element is found.

If the list contains `[1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2]`:

```
my_list.sort()  # will return [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
    if my_list[i] == my_list[i+1]:  
      return true

return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set()`

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,1]
newnums = set(numbers)
print (len(newnums) == len(numbers))
#True if the length is the same, False if the length is different
```

To put it in a function, see @buran's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53842031/9757927) and call it with:

```
check_no_duplicates(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting the `IndexError` is that, by using `numbers[n+1]`, you are accessing a value outside of the list boundaries.

The easiest way to get a list without duplicates is to convert it to a `set`, which automatically removes duplicates:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
myset = set(mylist) #myset is [1,2,3]
```

You can then check if there were any duplicates in the original list by comparing it to the list version of `myset`:

```
duplicatesinlist = mylist == list(myset)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def contains_duplicate(numbers):
    for n in range(len(numbers) - 1):          # see -1 in it
        if numbers[n] == numbers[n+1]:         # note: omitting your previous statement
            return True
    return False
```

---

*Tests:*

```
print(contains_duplicate([1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8]))
print(contains_duplicate([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]))
```

*Output:*

> ```
> True
> False
> ```